# Writing a proper search query with PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have been having issues trying to write a proper SQL search query with PHP using the Like keyword to generate ordered results based on the keywords entered.

**This is what I want to achieve**

If  I search for "Man thinking" , the result should come out like

Displaying results that match " Man thinking " --- 1st

Then Displaying results of  " Man "             --- 2nd

And then displaying results of " thinking "     ---3rd

I used the Like keyword like this below

```
select * from tablename where description like % Man thinking %
```

but it only generated random results and not ordered by the keyword string I used

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: http://use-the-index-luke.com - read this book. Wildard in front of query can seriously hinder your query speed. You might want to consider additional escaping of LIKE special characters: _ and %

Comment: if you want ranking you should be using a full text search

Comment: how can using wildcards hinder my query ?

Comment: To answer your last comment here, consider this -- when you have a wildcard in front of your query, it will look at all rows first to see if any of it has the value after the wildcard. If you have a value before the wildcard, it will match that first ( which will reduce the result set ) before doing a wildcard search.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9029354/243439

Answer (score 0):

The most basic answer to get you what you want is also using your conditions in the `ORDER BY` clause as follows:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `tablename`
WHERE
    description LIKE '%man thinking%' OR
    description LIKE '%man%' OR
    description LIKE '%thinking%'
ORDER BY
    description LIKE '%man thinking%' DESC,
    description LIKE '%man%' DESC,
    description LIKE '%thinking' DESC
```

I'm not aware of the performance overhead for this kind of query though.

Comment: Thanks for your help Merioles, But this might not generate RANKED results, but i'll try it though

Comment: A fulltext index will generate ranked results